# How to use Windows laptop as external monitor for Macbook Pro?

Tags: windows, macos

Is it possible to use a windows laptop as an external monitor for a macbook pro?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We should probably move this to ask different... I don7 t think I can do that though. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368042/windows-laptop-as-secondary-monitor-for-macbook-air-preferably-wired/368097#368097

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, check out [Maxivista](http://www.maxivista.com/) (for PC) and [ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html) (for Mac).

Comment: Can I mix & interchange this product in the two OSs together, or do they have to work homogenously?